# Error: shapes (2,7) and (2,7) not aligned: 7 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, compiler-errors

I have written the below code for implementing CBOW (Continuous Bag of Words), and get the error as above. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.
[The dimensions of x vector should be equal to dimension of concatenation of all context vectors being input for a particular word]

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.utils import np_utils
import tensorflow as tf
def tokenize(corpus):
    """Tokenize the corpus text.
    :param corpus: list containing a string of text (example: ["I like playing football with my friends"])
    :return corpus_tokenized: indexed list of words in the corpus, in the same order as the original corpus (the example above would return [[1, 2, 3, 4]])
    :return V: size of vocabulary
    """
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)
    corpus_tokenized = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(corpus)
    V = len(tokenizer.word_index)
    return corpus_tokenized, V

def corpus2io(corpus_tokenized, V, window_size):
    """Converts corpus text into context and center words
    # Arguments
        corpus_tokenized: corpus text
        window_size: size of context window
    # Returns
        context and center words (arrays)
    """
    for words in corpus_tokenized:
        L = len(words)
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            contexts = []
            labels = []
            s = index - window_size
            e = index + window_size + 1
            contexts.append([words[i]-1 for i in range(s, e) if 0 <= i < L and i != index])
            labels.append(word-1)
            x = np_utils.to_categorical(contexts, V)
            y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, V)
            yield (x, y.ravel())


def softmax(x):
    """Calculate softmax based probability for given input vector
    # Arguments
        x: numpy array/list
    # Returns
        softmax of input array
    """
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=0)

def cbow(context, label, W1, W2, loss):
    """
    Implementation of Continuous-Bag-of-Words Word2Vec model
    :param context: all the context words (these represent the inputs)
    :param label: the center word (this represents the label)
    :param W1: weights from the input to the hidden layer
    :param W2: weights from the hidden to the output layer
    :param loss: float that represents the current value of the loss function
    :return: updated weights and loss
    """
    x = np.mean(context, axis=0)
    h = np.dot(W1.T, x)
    u = np.dot(W2.T, h)
    y_pred = softmax(u)

    e = -label + y_pred
    dW2 = np.outer(h, e)
    dW1 = np.outer(x, np.dot(W2, e))

    new_W1 = W1 - eta * dW1
    new_W2 = W2 - eta * dW2

    loss += -float(u[label == 1]) + np.log(np.sum(np.exp(u)))

    return new_W1, new_W2, loss

N = 2 #assume that the hidden layer has dimensionality = 2
window_size = 2 #symmetrical
eta = 0.1 #learning rate

corpus_tokenized, V = tokenize(corpus)

#initialize weights (with random values) and loss function
np.random.seed(100)
W1 = np.random.rand(V, N)
W2 = np.random.rand(N, V)
loss = 0.

for i, (context, label) in enumerate(corpus2io(corpus_tokenized, V, window_size)):
    W1, W2, loss = cbow(context, label, W1, W2, loss)
    print("Training example #{} \n-------------------- \n\n \t label = {}, \n \t context = {}".format(i, label, context))
    print("\t W1 = {}\n\t W2 = {} \n\t loss = {}\n".format(W1, W2, loss))
```

Comment: I haven't checked your code entirely but the error should come from one of these 3 lines `h = np.dot(W1.T, x); u = np.dot(W2.T, h); dW1 = np.outer(x, np.dot(W2, e))`. You are doing matrix multiplication at these steps and for matrix multiplication your second dimension of the first array and first dimension of the second array should be same. Try to `print`  shapes of your `W1.T, x, W2.T, h, W2, e` before you execute their respective lines.